# ASP.Net Passing ViewModel to View (Underlying entity framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having problems passing a ViewModel into a view.

My ViewModel:

```
namespace ImpactDBASPNet.Models
{
    public class ComputerInfoViewModel
    {
        public List<string> CompanyList { get; set; }
        public tbl_computerinfo entitymodeleffort { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var tbl_computerinfo = db.tbl_computerinfo.Include(t => t.tbl_equipment);
        tbl_computerinfo = tbl_computerinfo.Where(c => c.Company == "Test Company");

        List<string> companylist = new List<string>();
        companylist.Add("Hello1");
        companylist.Add("hello2");

        ComputerInfoViewModel model = new ComputerInfoViewModel();
        model.CompanyList = companylist;
        model.entitymodeleffort = tbl_computerinfo;

        return View(model);
    }
```

I'm doing this primarily because I need to pass a list for a dropdownlist in my view, so I need to pass in the entity framework model AND the list. The error I am getting is:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ImpactDBASPNet.Models.tbl_computerinfo>' to 'ImpactDBASPNet.Models.tbl_computerinfo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    c:\impactdbaspnet\controllers\tbl_computerinfocontroller.cs 31  39  ImpactPortal
```

Comment: Your `.Where` clause generates `IEnumerable<tbl_computerinfo>`. Add `.FirstOrDefault()` to the end to return a single `tbl_computerinfo` (and you will probably want to test for `null`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Stephen. That generates the same error just reversed, IE cannot implicitly convert ImpactDBASPNet.Models.tbl_computerinfo to System.Linq.Iqueryable<ImpactDBASPNet.Models>tbl_computerinfo) it also keeps the existing error I had initially so now there are two errors instead of one.

Comment: Does not make sense. Did you do `tbl_computerinfo = tbl_computerinfo.Where(c => c.Company == "Test Company").FirstOrDefault();`?

Comment: OK, can see the problem - you need to change one of the variable names (the first line returns `IEnumerable<tbl_computerinfo>` but in the second line you trying to change the same variable to `tbl_computerinfo`). Instead do `var info = db.tbl_computerinfo.Include(t => t.tbl_equipment); tbl_computerinfo = info.Where(c => c.Company == "Test Company").FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Stephen, that worked. Many thanks for your help. If you want to turn that into an answer I'll mark it as the resolution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property `entitymodeleffort` is typeof `tbl_computerinfo` but you assigning `IEnumerable<tbl_computerinfo>` to it, resulting in the error. You need to use `FirstOrDefault()` (or one of the variants - `Single()` etc.) that returns a single `tbl_computerinfo` object.

Change the code to

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var tbl_computerinfo = db.tbl_computerinfo
   .Include(t => t.tbl_equipment)
   .Where(c => c.Company == "Test Company")
   .FirstOrDefault();
  List<string> companylist = new List<string>() { "Hello1", "Hello2" }; // save a few lines of code
  ComputerInfoViewModel model = new ComputerInfoViewModel();
  model.CompanyList = companylist;
  model.entitymodeleffort = tbl_computerinfo;
  return View(model);
}
```

Side note: Since `companylist` is used for a `dropdownlist`, you can make the property `SelectList`

```
public SelectList CompanyList { get; set; }
```

and

```
model.CompanyList = new SelectList(companylist);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.entitymodeleffort.SomeProperty, Model.CompanyList, ...)
```